# PHP equivalent of Python's func(*[args])

Tags: php, python, args

In Python I can do this:

```
def f(a, b, c):
    print a, b, c

f(*[1, 2, 3])
```

How do you say this in PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [call_user_func_array](http://www.php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
call_user_func_array('f', array(1, 2, 3));
```

If you wanted to call a class method, you'd use `array($instance, 'f')` instead of `'f'` and if it was a static class function you'd use `array('ClassName', 'f')` or `'ClassName::f'`. See the [callback type docs](http://de.php.net/callback#language.types.callback) for details about that.

Comment: this is ugly, but in the question, he knows all the parameters, so you can also `$f = 'fname'; $f(1,2,3);` and, if it's an object method, you can `$o->{$f}(1,2,3);`

Comment: My eyes, the goggles, they do nothing!  Reminds me why I now code in Python when I can...

Comment: He wanted to pass the arguments from an array though (which is exactly what a *array arg in python does).